# Worst case scenario in Linear Programming with variable constraints

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I have a linear optimization problem:

```
minimize c^T x
where A x = b
```

But I want to find the 'worst case scenario' when b is flexible (`m_i < b_i < M_i`). A naive approach would be applying a non-linear optimization to the linear one:

```
maximize [minimize c^T x where A x = b] where b_min < b < b_max
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Maybe a real example: 
The famous diet problem, where we look for a cheapest combination of foods that satisfy all nutritional requirements. But as nutritional requirements aren't completely set (and depend on person and his daily activity), constraints are flexible and we want to find a worst case scenario - what would be most expensive set of constraints - if food combination is optimized.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilevel_optimization - this is basically what I need, I'll try the linked optimizer and post the result.

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand what you mean. If I keep 2 levels of optimization, then b is of course a decision variable for the top level optimization. But as the outer level optimization is complex, I'm not exactly sure how to do it.   

Of course it would be optimal to keep only one level of optimization, but then I'm not sure how could I use b as a decision variable?

Comment: But how, what would be the objective coefficients as b variables have no value.

Comment: Sorry, I initially misread the problem as `min_b [min_x cx; Ax=b]`. One well-known way to solve linear bilevel problems is to formulate the first order conditions of the inner problem, and thus replacing the inner optimization problem by a set of equations.

Comment: How about [Sensitivity Analysis for Linear Programming](http://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/AMP-Chapter-03.pdf)?

Comment: This is the problem that [robust optimization](http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~nemirovs/FullBookDec11.pdf) solves. The interval in which `b` has to be is called the *uncertainty set*. A classic paper that may be of help to you is [this](http://www.robustopt.com/references/Price%20of%20Robustness.pdf)